# How do I get byte-compilation warnings about undefined variables?

Tags: elisp-macros, byte-compilation

The following code works fine with `M-x eval-buffer`, and byte-compiles without any warnings.

```lisp
(eval-when-compile
  (defconst demo-one 1))

(defvar demo-some-var
  `(foo bar ,demo-one))
```

However, if I byte compile it, I get broken code:

```
;ELC
;;; Compiled
;;; in Emacs version 26.1
;;; with all optimizations.

;;; This file uses dynamic docstrings, first added in Emacs 19.29.

;;; This file does not contain utf-8 non-ASCII characters,
;;; and so can be loaded in Emacs versions earlier than 23.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;


(defvar demo-some-var (list 'foo 'bar demo-one))
```

The byte compiler hasn't put `demo-one` in the .elc file, so anyone installing my package from (M)ELPA gets broken code.

I should be using `eval-and-compile` in this case, but I didn't realise my code was wrong. Can the byte compiler warn me here? Why didn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The byte-compiler attempts to catch such cases w.r.t functions that are defined at compile-time but not at run-time (resulting in warnings along the lines of "These function are not known to be defined at run-time"), but it makes no similar efforts for variables.  This probably deserves a feature request.

Comment: Filed #36445 :)

Answer (score 1):

For understanding why `demo-one` is undefined when loading your byte compiled file it is best to recall the main application of `eval-when-compile`.

The sense of the following code is **not** to put `(require 'my-nifty-macro-package)` into the compiled file but to ensure during byte compilation that the macros from `my-nifty-macro-package` are known, i.e., to load the library `my-nifty-macro-package` **when compilation** happens.

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'my-nifty-macro-package))
```

Since the macros are already expanded in the byte compiled code the package `my-nifty-macro-package` is no longer needed for loading the byte compiled file. Therefore one excludes the line `(require 'my-nifty-macro-package)` from the byte compiled code with `eval-when-compile`.

You should put the code `(defconst demo-one 1)` simply into your source file without any additional hocus-pocus. That code is put behind the byte compiled function definitions in the compiled file.

About your actual question

> How do I get byte-compilation warnings about undefined variables?

The thing is that you did work very hard to avoid the warning even if `demo-one` is undefined in the byte compiled file. You defined it during byte compilation and you did explicitly exclude it from the byte compiled code with `eval-when-compile`.

Remove the `eval-when-compile`.
If you also remove `(defconst demo-one 1)` and you use `demo-one` without `let`-binding you get a warning.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that even if removing the constant definition worked as OP expected, it would have the negative effect of getting rid of documentation.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 I am not quite sure what you mean. The OP would use `(eval-and-compile
  (defconst test 1 "Some doc"))` which does compile and provide the doc string in the compiled file. (Even if it is not contained in its original form in the compiled file. It is rather contained as constant string that can be re-used.)

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 The worst thing in omitting a `defvar` or `defconst` is that the variable is not made special in the concerned file. That can have very strange effects in connection with lexical scoping.

Comment: Thanks for examples of when `eval-when-compile` is useful!

I agree that `defconst` on its own is generally better, but I wasn't able to do that here because `syntax-propertize-rules` produces a compilation warning.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that you can get everything you (seem to) want using macros.  For instance:

```lisp
(eval-when-compile (defmacro demo-one () 1))

(defvar demo-some-var `(foo bar ,(demo-one)))
```

Now, when you construct `demo-some-var`, the macro will compile and run, and it will be as if you set `(defvar demo-some-var '(foo bar 1))` directly.  Further more, since your macro will only be used in this compiled context, it is now safe to wrap its entire definition in `eval-when-compile`, thus removing it from the `.elc` file.

You should know that `defconst` doesn't behave like (say) a C preprocessor macro.  It is a variable that the Emacs Lisp interpreter must look for.  So when you compile it out of existence in `eval-when-compile`, and then reference it in `demo-some-var`'s definition, this is incorrect.

As to why it works when you run `eval-buffer`, the `eval-when-compile` function has the following behavior:

- It is evaluated into the compiler when compiling a source file.
- It is not placed into the byte-compiled output when compiling a source file.
- When evaluated (i.e., no compilation involved, as in `eval-buffer`), it is always run.

So your the Emacs session in which you ran `eval-buffer` *has* the definition of `demo-one`, but any `.elc` you compiled, will have it stripped away.  For more on `eval-when-compile`, check the Emacs function documentation with `C-h f eval-when-compile`, or the online Emacs manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Time-of-Evaluation.html